# What do you understand from this? Is this person a football player?

Tags: reading, comprehension

"I have always wanted to be a footballer. I am very happy because my dreams have come true. I don't see football as a job for me. I used to enjoy it, I still do."

This is not the full text but this part is probably the most important part. Is this person a football player? Because while reading this I thought this part had some kind of "contradiction"(idk if I am using the word correctly) in it. And I thought that the person didn't become a football player but still enjoyed playing football in his free time???  To be honest, the text was full of grammatical mistakes and one sentence had five "then"s in it. I am not fluent in English yet, however I can recognize some grammatical mistakes too. And instead of using "ball" or idk maybe "football ball" the person who wrote this chose to use "football"=> "I always wanted a football, then my dad bought me a football as present" this was in the text too. I am confused????

Comment: The name of the ball used in football (in the US the sport is called  "soccer") is indeed *a football*

Comment: In Britain "football player" is almost always shortened to "footballer". If you do it for a living you are a "professional footballer". But if it is purely for your own pleasure, and to keep fit, you are an "amateur footballer".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - And just for completeness, the name of the ball used in American football is *a football* and the name of the ball in soccer is *a soccer ball*.  :-)

Comment: Guys surely no need to add comments to questions that should be migrated

Comment: @Jim: You mean, a handegg?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - Well, I immediately see the meaning, but i’ve never in my life heard that, so, no, that’s not whst I meant.  ;-)

Comment: @Jim It is what you meant, you just didn't know that it was what you meant ;) https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=handegg

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Good point. Etymologically "ball" is cognate with "sphere".  See OED: *Probably the reflex of an unattested Old English *beall (compare Old English bealluc bollock n.), cognate with Middle Dutch bal ball, sphere (Dutch bal ball, sphere, ball of the foot, heel of the hand), Middle Low German bal ball, ball of the foot, heel of the hand, Old High German bal ball for playing, small sphere, mouthful (Middle High German bal ball, globe, ball of the foot, German Ball )...Compare bale n.3 for forms in Romance languages probably borrowed ultimately < the same Germanic base*.

Comment: footballer is a British term. In the US, a soccer player. Though some, like me, also insist of saying football. Ergo, in the UK, a football is a soccer ball.

Answer (score 3):

From this fragment I can understand, that the person in question is indeed a football player. That person has always dreamt about being a footballer (say, in their childhood), and now he (I presume it's a he) has become one. Even though he's a professional player now, he still cherishes the game itself and not the income he's getting from it. I don't know the context, but that's how I see it. Unless you mean the very word "footballer", but this is already explained in the above comments.

Comment: It's best to add the explanation "above" in the answer for several reasons: 1. comments are sometimes deleted by their authors or by the system. 2. If many other comments are added (seems unlikely but you never know) it will be difficult to know which one you are referring to. 3. Good answers are self contained. you are not stealing anyone's glory by adding their comment in your answer, but it's nice to add an attribution.

Comment: It's best to *not* answer questions that should be on the learner's site

Comment: Our english teachers said he wasn't a football player but I don't trust them anyway. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @PrynHoho what's the title of the textbook or school book you are using? I *might* have a copy of it at home. Sometimes the extra context helps to clear up any confusion. If it was written on the blackboard or given in a handout, then I'm afraid you're going to have to ask the teacher to explain why the speaker is *not* a footballer.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A unfortunately the text was written by another english teacher, but yesterday our english teacher said that she changed her mind after reading the text with a clear mind. She realised the man was indeed a footballer. So you guys' explanations are correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this person a football player?

**Yes.**

> "I have always wanted to be a footballer."

Not useful information yet. Just information about a dream. A dream to be a footballer, i.e. somebody who plays the sport "football" (either professionally or otherwise).

> "I am very happy because my dreams have come true."

Now we have a statement of fact: the dream came true. **He is a footballer.**

> "I don't see football as a job for me. I used to enjoy it, I still do."

This is a bit of an idiom, but from it we can understand that:

- it *is* a job for him (so he is a *professional* footballer); and
- he nonetheless mentally considers it to *not* be a like a job, purely because it's so much fun!

We'll ignore the comma splice in the final sentence…

> "I always wanted a football, then my dad bought me a football as present"

This part is fairly self-explanatory. Yes, a football is a round thing that you kick. ⚽ A football is the name of the kind of ball that is used in the game "football" (lol). He always wanted one, so it was nice that his dad bought him one. No doubt this helped with his career preparations!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Our English teacher wrote that part to confuse students into thinking that he is a football player. But I think she kind of messed up while trying to create a "contradiction" (I still don't know if I am using this word correctly).

Comment: @PrynHoho Again, I don't think that this is [ultimately] contradictory. To native speakers, it wouldn't be confusing. I can understand why it might be to non-native speakers! The idiom seems contradictory, because it employs, I don't know, it's not sarcasm, but ...